# Finding out whether rsync modified target?

Tags: rsync

My program copies/synchronizes several directories from source to target, each using rsync. For each directory, if the version in target is not identical to source, and thus rsync modifies the target, I would like to notify the user with a message like "directory X has been synchronized to target". On the other hand, if target version is already identical to target, I can skip showing this message since there is no change in target.

Exit status and -n option do not differentiate between the two condition. Aside from parsing the output of -v, is there any other way for me to get rsync to provide this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may do the job:

```
rsync --log-format=%f ...
```

Note that rsync outputs files anytime any attribute changes, not only if the content of the file is updated.

There is also a `-i` option (or `--log-format=%i`) that itemizes all of the changes.  See the rsync man page for details of the output format.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try --log-format=SomeUniqueString which makes the rsync output easily grep-able to detect modified/added files. For files deleted in target, I'll still have to parse /^deleting /m pattern.